# Why NodePort service type has to use ClusterIP based load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes

When reading through the kubernetes document I noticed that NodePort type service always automatically creates a ClusterIP and ingress traffic targeting NodePort will be routed to ClusterIP. My question is that why is this necessary? Why can't kubeproxy directly does load balancing for this NodePort through forwarding? ClusterIP doesn't seem to be necessary to support NodePort and it seems to introduce additional overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Even `Service` of type `NodePort` does not directly contact Pods, they still go through the Service's cluster IP, and its associated Pod selector rules. With newer kubernetes I think you can also influence whether traffic is round-robin or weighted distributed, which wouldn't work if the NodePort directly contacted the Pods

Also, NodePorts are opened on **every** member of the cluster, but -- in most cases -- you don't have a Pod running on *every* member of the cluster, so it still has to use the Service IP to route to the actual Node upon which an in-service Pod can service that traffic.

Think of NodePorts an a mechanism to bridge the "outside world" with the "cluster world," rather than a shortcut mechanism to side-step iptables or ipvs

Comment: what you mean by "weighted distributed traffic"? Does Kubernetes has this feature already?

Comment: It does, yes, since 1.11: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the reason is really that we want to unify the load balancing handling.

Comment: For the scenario that you described above, we can also let the ingress traffic targeting NodePort go through kubeproxy directly and forward it to kubeproxy running on nodes hosting the target pods. Why wouldn't this work?


If we are saying that NodePort is by design a way of bridging the two worlds and we intentionally don't want to introduce another route for LB, that seems to be a reasonable design decision.

Comment: If you are that concerned about kube-proxy and getting into the weeds of the traffic routing, then use a CNI provider that allocates "real" addresses for Pods and that entire conversation evaporates. Or you can set `hostNetwork: true` on those Pods and run the risk of having port collisions from co-scheduled Pods on the same Node

Comment: I wa just curious why the design for NodePort is this way since it seems to be possible to implement it without relying on ClusterIP. Not really a concern yet.